# Copy parent case data to child case

Tags: case

I have 50+ fields on case object. There are multiple related/child cases under one parent case. The parent case is populated with some data. Is there a way through which we can copy data from parent case to child case as soon as child cases are created as the parent and child case have same fields?

Note: I already know that it can be done via process builder by using update feature and mapping parent and child fields but it's such a waste of time because I have 50+ fields so it will take  along time. Is there a quicker way to just copy data from parent to child?

2. I also know that I can create formula fields on child cases but it will be unnecessarily repetition of same fields e.g field 'Description' already exists on both Parent and Child case. I just want to copy the data rather than creating a formula field on child case with the name 'Description 2' that references the 'Description' field on parent case.

Kindly let me know if there is a time saving and efficient solution?

Thanks

Comment: You just clone the parent case and update parentId to create child case

Comment: @Santanu Boral: This sounds like manual process. Can it be automated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably go with a trigger and the [`sObject.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getPopulatedFieldsAsMap) method.

When the child case is created you have the trigger query all the parent cases fields that you want to copy over. Then run through the getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() Map keys and copy the values from the parent case to the child case using `.get(field)` and `.put(field)`.

It would also be worth bulkifying so that each parent case is only only queried once and then mapped back to the appropriate child case.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This sounds like a good approach as I will only have to write the code once. Rest the trigger will take care of it. I will work on implementing this. Thanks again.

Comment: @Student The only outstanding question is how dynamic you want to make it. As proposed, the fixed SOQL query for the parent case would define which fields are cloned. If you want to go all in on making it dynamic you could use the Case field metadata to build the SOQL query with just those fields that can be cloned.